# How to dynamic set the RecyclerView item height?

Tags: dynamic, android-recyclerview

I want to make the recyclerview itme keep same Aspect ratio in any screen(the Aspect ratio is 8:5)；So How to dynamic set the  RecyclerView item heigh?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set its width and height programmatically, you need to use ViewGroup.LayoutParams

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams= recyclerview.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = height;
layoutParams.widht = width
recyclerview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

You need to pass the `height` and `width` to it according to what you desire.
I used `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, but you can use whatever ViewGroup you put the recyclerview in. If it's inside a LinearLayout, you'll use LinearLayout.LayoutParams and so on.

Let me know if it worked for you and remember to upvote/select answer as correct if it did, cheers

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html

Here is the example: Add this implementation

`'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'` to your dependencies.

And this is your reyclerview configuration :

```
val layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(this)
layoutManager.flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW
layoutManager.justifyContent = JustifyContent.FLEX_START
recyclerview.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

You can check this gist also https://gist.github.com/siifii/3edd8cd2d4f5a9b4672b9976c0c55ff4

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.